# Inserting document to MongoDB from mongodump JSON with pymongo

Tags: json, mongodb, pymongo

I have a JSON file (converted from mongodump BSON) which I would like to insert to a MongoDB using pymongo.
The approach I am using is something like:

```
with open('duplicate_docs.json') as f:
    lines = f.readlines() 

    for line in lines:
        record = json.loads(line)
        db.insert_one(record)
```

However, the JSON is in the form:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId( "54ccc3f469702d45ca450200"), \"id\":\"54713efd69702d78d1420500\",\"name\":\"response"}
```

As you can see there are escape charaters () for the JSON keys and I am not able to load this as a JSON.
What is the best way yo fix a JSON string like this so it can be used to do insert to MongoDB?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative approach if you take the actual output of mongodump you can insert it straight in with the `bson.json_util` `loads()` function.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.json_util import loads

db = MongoClient()['mydatabase']

with open('c:/temp/duplicate_docs.json', mode='w') as f:
    f.write('{"_id":{"$oid":"54ccc3f469702d45ca450200"},"id":"54713efd69702d78d1420500","name":"response"}')
    
with open('c:/temp/duplicate_docs.json') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

    for line in lines:
        record = loads(line)
        db.docs.insert_one(record)
```

Answer (score 1):

why not use **mongoexport** to dump to **json** not **bson**

`mongoexport --port 27017 --db <database> --collection <collection> --out output.json`

and then use

`mongoimport --port 27017 --db <database> --collection <collection> --file output.json`

Comment: Unfornately my Mongo version is 2.6 and Mongoexport does not support it.

Comment: @madu ah i see. then as suggested @Belly above, you need to replace `ObjectId("54ccc3f469702d45ca450200")` with `"_id": {"$oid": "5ef990c9bebbdd790e731b26"}`